# Angular 8 and Okta logout not working as user is redirected inside the app

Tags: angular, angular8, openid-connect, okta, okta-api

I have implemented Okta authentication in my Angular 8 app. When I hit logout button the session is terminated and I am logged out of Okta app but as my logout URL configured in okta is for `localhost:4200/dashboard` it redirects me to the `dashboard` component. Post successful logout I want to navigate user to `localhost:4200/login`. I have two questions, I tried

```
 async logOut(){
await this.oauthService.logout();
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
// but this does not redirect user to login.
```

and also, I tried asking Okta support that logout button is in navbar and can be hit from different URLs and not necessarily `localhost:4200/dashboard` as navbar is on every single page of my application. They mentioned it can only be configured from a single URL path. How can I implement the logout from different components and hence different URL paths.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to register a Post Logout Redirect URI and can then trigger logout from any location within your app.

I would implement it like this:

- Provide a post logout landing page
- Provide a re-login option on that page

Some resources of mine that might give you some ideas:

- [Logout blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/24/logout/)
- [Working logout code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts)